# How to assign drawable to ImageView in acitvity using Kotlin as language

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to set and reset the Drawable resource of ImageView from activity, but the IDE is showing cannot assign a value to Val.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing what you tried and showing what specifically the IDE is pointing to as the source of the error.

Comment: This was very helpful even without a non working example in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using the following code:

```
        image_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_drawable_file)
```

For more information please refer the following link:

https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/03/android-kotlin-imageview-set-image.html

Answer (score 2):

`val` is not possible to change. You can set image in image by directly calling the ImageView in your onCreate like this:

```
Imageviewid.background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.imageid)
```

Alternatively, you can to change your `val` to a `var`